# How can I create a word merge document with an MS Access table using multiple rows

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, mailmerge

I need to create a mail merge document using an MS Access table.  The word document will be a letter to a member that has selected his or her benefits for their companies open enrollment period.  Each record in the table represents a different Benefit Type Selection.  For instance there will be one record for Jon Smith's DENTAL Selection, one record for Jon Smith's MEDICAL selection, one record for Jon Smith's VISION selection.  In the mail merge document, each mail merge document must be grouped by the member.  For instance the document will say something along the lines of "Dear Jon, You have selected the following benefits: "Dental: XYZ Carrier, Medical: ABC Company Carrier, and Vision: Vision Carriers for You, for the upcoming 2020 plan year."

How do I make this happen using MS Access and MS Word 2010?  I am well versed  in VBA if there needs to be a vba solution but I feel like I should be able to accomplish this with simple mail merge tools.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: An Access report won't accomplish this output? Your question is really too broad for SO.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you looked at using Word's built-in mail merge? This actually belongs in an end-user forum (Super User), not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to fix your data by using the query wizard and making a cross tab table.  This will align all benefits in one row.  The next part is on mailmerge.

Mailmerge is a feature-rich tool in Word.  First, type up the letter like if you were trying to send it to just one person.  Next in the mailing tab click on select "recipient list" and click on use existing list.  Choose the corresponding source, MS Access database.

Next, delete the first item you want to be populated by the mail merge.  For example the name.  Then click on the "Insert Merge Field and select the field with names.  Repeat the process for all items you need to extract from the database.

It will look like this.
[image]

After that click on finished and merge.

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions and answers. If a problem can be solved using end-user tools neither question nor answer belong here. In that case, the user needs to be directed - through a comment - to an end-user site.

Comment: That 'answer' won't satisfy the OP's requirement for grouping by member, for which see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/142710-post2.html